# Heteroskedasticity- is everything over for my model?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, nonlinear-regression

So, I've got this exponential model:
[image: model-visual]
[image: dr.]

Which, when tested via Pagan- Breusch, got heteroskedasticity detected.

---

Breusch-Pagan / Cook-Weisberg test for heteroskedasticity 
         Ho: Constant variance
         Variables: var2

```
     chi2(1)      =   760.75
     Prob > chi2  =   0.0000
```

And visualy:

[image: ...]

My question, then, is: is there anything I can do to "save" my model?

Comment: Heteroscedasticity is not the chief problem: your exponential curve doesn't even remotely fit the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are regressing GDP time series then you should apply log-transformation to the GDP. Two popular ways of modeling GDP are:

$$\ln GDP_t=c + g t + \varepsilon_t$$
and
$$\ln GDP_{t+1}-\ln GDP_t = g + \varepsilon_t$$

The first one is exponential growth, the second one geometric brownian motion. In any case you have to apply log, otherwise the heteroscedasticity will show up